# can't style an image in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the margins of an image under a div "text" but it's not detecting any styling. I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please advice.

Here is the HTML

```
 <div class="text">
    <h2> <img src="/static/meddy1/images/ad.png" alt ="Ads"><a href="/docprofile/{{doc.id}}/">{{doc.name}}</a></h2>
    <h3 id="gray" style="margin-top: -10px;"> {{doc.clinic.address_normal}}</h3>
 </div>
```

here is the CSS

```
.text {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.text > img {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Images are `inline` elements and not affected by margins...change the `display` property to `inline-block` or `block` and see what happens.

Comment: @Paulie_D I could be wrong, but I was under the impression that images are `inline-block` by default, because otherwise they wouldn't naturally be affected by `width` and `height`.

Comment: use `.text img` instead of `.text > img`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Not according to this - http://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/

Comment: @Paulie_D Just tested it for myself, you're indeed correct.

Comment: Phew...thought I was going crazy there for a minute. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text > img` is looking for a first-level child, but your image is a *second*-level child.

Try `.text > h2 > img` or `.text img` - note that the second one may cause issues if you have other images in your `.text` element.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not css expert but .text > img means immediate child of .text, it's not the case. Your code is .text > h2 > img.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ">" indicates a direct child, whereas your DOM shows that the image is actually a child of the h2 element beneath text. So, to fix it, you should use the descendant selector, instead:

```
.text img
```

In short "x > y" means select "y" with a direct parent of "x", while "x y" means select "y" if it has an ancestor (at any level) that matches "x".